# Can the word mnemonic be used adverbally?

Tags: word-choice, is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology

A ***mnemonic*** is a memory device for reducing something diverse and complicated to an easily -remembered pattern. For example, for the order of planets in the solar system, I learned as a boy the sentence:

*Men very easily make jugs, serve useful necessary purposes*; to give *Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune, Pluto*.

Is there an adverb *mnemonically*, as in *I am able to recite all the kings and queens of England, mnemonically*.

Comment: I remember them mnemonically as well, but with "*My very educated mother just served us nine pies*."

Comment: The adverbial use you suggest, @WS2, couples the verb recite awkwardly to a device for remembering. That would be like saying "I am able to fish for bass and trout "baitally". Baitally is the imaginary adverbial form of bait. I fish with the help of bait; I recite with the help of a mnemonic. Even so, Jim's use is spot on, and I would use mnemonically too. Adverbial meaning, with the assistance of a mnemonic.

Comment: However, "mnemonically" reads well and is easily understood; whereas "baitally" reads awkwardly and is not readily understood. I think that difference should play a role in deciding such issues.

Comment: @Jim There is no more 'pie'.

Comment: @Mitch- Yeah, too bad- I really like pie.  Now it'll have to be ... just served us nachos.

Comment: http://www.xkcd.com/473/

Comment: I find absolutely nothing objectionable about the use of *mnemonically* in your example. Though it's not a word most people would need to employ daily, I'd certainly use it if the occasion merited it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course there is. There <sub><sup>**HAS**</sup></sub> to be: you can always add *‑ally* to an *‑ic* adjective to derive an adverb of manner from it.  The key here is realizing that *mnemonic* can serve as an adjective as well as it can serve as a noun.

No dictionary lists all possible words produced by derivational morphology. That doesn’t mean it isn’t a word.  Obviously, it’s a word. In this instance, the OED even happens to have a citation for it:

> 1867 *Q. Rev.* Oct. 427 ― Each one of these mysterious letters was taken, mnemonically, as the initial of some technical word that indicated one of these four methods.

Predictably, *mnemonically* simply means in a mnemonic manner, just like all such derived adverbs do, mutatis mutandis.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check the OED before I posted. My everyday dictionary (Oxford Dictionaries) didn't even show it as an adjective. Anyway thanks.